# How to make symbols in vim highlighted?

Tags: vim, syntax-highlighting

I found that many symbols in vim, such as comma, the equal symbol etc, are not highlighted by default, no matter which filetype I'm working on.

Therefore I wonder how can I highlight these symbols and apply to all filetypes?

Thank you.

Comment: Why do you think should they be highlighted?

Comment: when you have a key highlighted in blue on the left and its value highlighted in green on the right, the white `:` in the middle *is* highlighted.

Comment: @romainl  @IngoKarkat  oftentimes most of my code are not highlighted, for example, `int variable = getValue()` , no word or symbols are highlighted except `int` :-(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try in vimrc

```
autocmd FileType * call <SID>def_base_syntax() " autocmd Syntax may be better
function! s:def_base_syntax()
  " Simple example
  syntax match commonOperator "\(+\|=\|-\|\^\|\*\)"
  syntax match baseDelimiter ","
  hi link commonOperator Operator
  hi link baseDelimiter Special
endfunction
```

or If you want to append syntax each filetypes.
You should use `$HOME/.vim/after/syntax/bar.vim`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it did work! but not for multi symbols. Actually I don't know how to handle it. I'm not good at vimscripts, so please tell me how to apply these to more symbols at the same time. Very grateful!

Comment: My pleasure. Vim syntax highlighting is worked by text matching pattern likes regular expression. I would give some example for answer. And you want to know more information, there is default syntax script in `$VIMRUNTIME/syntax/` or `:help syntax` is help you. Sorry for my poor English. :)

Comment: Thank you very much !! my problem since long ago has eventually been solved :)